# ENOENT webpack-dev-server esm

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops, webpack-dev-server, es6-modules

I inherited a react project hosted on azure-devops.
Cloned local repository
Need to downgrade npm and node versions to:
npm@6.14.8
node@v14.14.0
After that successfully install modules (npm i)

but now I can not run npm start and it's getting me this error.

npm start

```
> @0.1.0 start 
> node -r esm scripts/run-webpack.js webpack-dev-server

spawn called
[Arguments] {
  '0': '\\node_modules\\.bin\\webpack-dev-server',
  '1': [ '-r', 'esm', '--mode=development', '--color' ],
  '2': {
    env: { NODE_ENV: 'development' },
    windowsHide: true,
    stdio: 'inherit'
  }
}
Error: spawn \node_modules\.bin\webpack-dev-server ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:269:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
    at process.runNextTicks [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/task_queues.js:62:3)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:465:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
    at process.runNextTicks [as _tickCallback] (internal/process/task_queues.js:62:3)
    at \Frontend\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:34535
    at \Frontend\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:34176
    at process.<anonymous> (\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:34506)
    at Function.<anonymous> (\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:296856)
    at Function.<anonymous> (\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:296555)
    at Function.<anonymous> (\node_modules\esm\esm.js:1:284879) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn \\node_modules\\.bin\\webpack-dev-server',
  path: '\\node_modules\\.bin\\webpack-dev-server',
  spawnargs: [ '-r', 'esm', '--mode=development', '--color' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @0.1.0 start: `node -r esm scripts/run-webpack.js webpack-dev-server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     \AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-16T09_23_36_828Z-debug.log
```

Log here:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   '\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.14.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle @0.1.0~prestart: @0.1.0
6 info lifecycle @0.1.0~start: @0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle @0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @0.1.0~start: PATH: \nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;\node_modules\.bin;\Python39\Scripts\;\Python39\;\Java\jre1.8.0_281\bin; (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;\Ruby23-x64\bin;\Ruby23-x64\bin;\Windows\system32;\Windows;\Windows\System32\Wbem;\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\; (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;\TortoiseSVN\bin;\Git\cmd; (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\; (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\; (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\; (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;\devkit\mingw\bin; (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;\jruby-9.1.17.0\bin;\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;\WINDOWS\system32;\WINDOWS;\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;\TortoiseGit\bin; (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;\WINDOWS\system32;\WINDOWS;\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;\dotnet\;\Azure Data Studio\bin;\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;\nodejs\;\jruby-9.1.17.0\bin;\Ruby23-x64\bin;\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;\.dotnet\tools;\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;;\Azure Data Studio\bin;\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle @0.1.0~start: CWD: 
10 silly lifecycle @0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node -r esm scripts/run-webpack.js webpack-dev-server' ]
11 silly lifecycle @0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: @0.1.0 start: `node -r esm scripts/run-webpack.js webpack-dev-server`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid @0.1.0
15 verbose cwd 
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
17 verbose argv "\\nodejs\\node.exe" "\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v14.14.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @0.1.0 start: `node -r esm scripts/run-webpack.js webpack-dev-server`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I have tried everything in my power but nothing worked and now I am desperate, please help!

Comment: Hi @LeoLiu-MSFT, thank you for your effort, but in the end it appers that was old branch (not working at all) and now I got new repo where webpack-dev-server hasn't use anymore (now vite) and everything is working now :/

Answer (score 0):

> ENOENT webpack-dev-server esm

According to the error message, it seems this issue related to the `webpack-dev-server`.

So, please try to access the command webpack-dev-server, you could try to set a command in npm's package.json file like

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server -d --config webpack.dev.config.js --content-base public/ --progress --colors"
   }
```

Or you could try to install the script in global scope as well before you run the npm start:

```
sudo npm install -g webpack-dev-server
```